# React Jest Unit Testing await in private function uncovered line

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage, istanbul

I call a async function in useEffect

```
 const [documents, setDocuments] = useState(Array());

  async function findDocuments() {
    const res = await findDocumentList([], {});
    setDocuments(res.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    findDocuments();
  }, []);
```

I'm seeing `state not covered` issue in my coverage report.

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The coverage report needs every async function to have an await on it: `await findDocuments()`